What is the difference between the foliation of a manifold and a mere partitioning?
I'm unable to visualize a partitioning that isn't also a foliation, and I need to so I can understand The Stretched Horizon and Black Hole Complementarity
In particular, I don't understand how curves in adjacent partitions that touch could not be tangent.

I don't understand that paper myself, but does this kind of thing address your question? Partition $\mathbb{R}^3$ into lines parallel to the $x$ axis (if their $z$ coordinate is rational) or the $y$-axis (if their $z$ coordinate is irrational).

So the difference is that some curves in a folated partition must touch? That seems like a mighty strange distinction. Maybe that would allow momentum moving along those curves to be passed from one partition to the next without any work being done. I don't know. It's one of a whole lot of things I don't know.

Can you say what particularly in that long paper you are looking at? I can't find the words 'adjacent' or 'tangent' in it. And the only relevant mention of 'partition' seems to be on page 4, but not sure how that relates to your question. (I replaced the tag by ones that might attract attention by mathematical relativists.)

To simplify things and to avoid misunderstanding, it should be good if you could report the exact definitions and the settings of "partition" and "foliation" you are referring to.

Okay, those words are from the definiton of foliation, a term that appears in the paper. I read it until I bumped into "foliation."  I looked up the term, didn't understand how it's different from partitioning, so I asked here.

Here is a variation of Martin M. W.'s example: consider the foliation of $R^2$ whose leaves are simply vertical lines. Between any two vertical lines in the plane, there are infinitely many others, so it does not make sense to say that two distinct vertical lines are adjacent. And if you have two distinct vertical lines in the plane, it does not make sense to speak of them touching or being tangent to one another, either. Partitions are much more general: you could partition the plane into the top half, bottom half, and horizontal axis, and that's a partition but not a foliation.

ok, that answers my question. A foliation requires at least one tangent curve. I think. But it's close enough.  Copy and paste what you said into an answer and get points!

Oops, too late! A question about foliation/partitioning of n-manifolds is a stupid question. Right. Stax doesn't deserve it's reputation.
